# Uploaded a File succesfully on google drive using Python with PyDrive but File is damaged

Tags: python-3.x, pydrive

I am trying to upload a file from my computer to google drive using Python(Pydrive), it gets uploaded succesfully but gets damaged and its size becomes 0kb.

Here is my code:

```
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
import glob, os
with open('C:\\Users\\New\\Pictures\\Screenshots\\older\\Screenshot.png', 'r') as file:
          fn = os.path.basename(file.name)
          file_drive = drive.CreateFile({"title": fn })
file_drive.Upload()
print('The file: ' + fn + ' has been uploaded')
print('Successful')
```

What I am doing wrong? I have done the Authentication part and it's Authenticated successfully.

I have checked answers related to this but I didn't get the answer I am looking for.

Comment: Size of the file ? Python version ? Pydrive version ?

Comment: Seeing as you're on Windows, perhaps you should open with `'rb'`? I.e., `open(somepath, 'rb')`

Comment: @RMPR size of file is 131 KB.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel I have tried it but it didn't work, i mean file gets uploaded but it gets damaged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to upload a file of `C:\\Users\\New\\Pictures\\Screenshots\\older\\Screenshot.png'` to Google Drive using pydrive with python.
- You have already been able to use Drive API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification point:

- In your script, the file content is not given.

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

From:

```
with open('C:\\Users\\New\\Pictures\\Screenshots\\older\\Screenshot.png', 'r') as file:
          fn = os.path.basename(file.name)
          file_drive = drive.CreateFile({"title": fn })
file_drive.Upload()
```

To:

```
f = 'C:\\Users\\New\\Pictures\\Screenshots\\older\\Screenshot.png'  # Added
with open(f, 'r') as file:  # Modified
          fn = os.path.basename(file.name)
          file_drive = drive.CreateFile({"title": fn })
file_drive.SetContentFile(f)  # Added
file_drive.Upload()
```

#### References:

- [Upload and update file content](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/filemanagement.html?highlight=upload#upload-and-update-file-content)
- [SetContentFile(filename)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/pydrive.html#pydrive.files.GoogleDriveFile.SetContentFile)

If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: That actually worked for me, now i can see the image. Thanks.

Comment: @ankur singh Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.